# Get value from JTable to set into JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, textfield

I try to get value from `JTable` to put into `JTextField` when clicking the mouse but it doesn't work. For instance when user selects a row from my table, `JTextField` populates with information that is at selected row dynamically.

Also my `JTable` is in a `JScrollPane`. Also my table has a `DefaultTableModel`.

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(){
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column){
        return false;
        }
    };
private JTable jTable1 = new JTable(model);
public Reservation() {
    try {
        jbInit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void jbInit() throws Exception {
    this.getContentPane().setLayout( null );
    this.setSize( new Dimension(400, 300) );
    this.setTitle( "Rezervasyon" );
    jLabel1.setText("Kitap No: ");
    jLabel1.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 185, 60, 15));
    jTextField1.setBounds(new Rectangle(60, 180, 70, 20));
    jLabel2.setText("Ogrenci No: ");
    jLabel2.setBounds(new Rectangle(165, 180, 65, 20));
    jTextField2.setBounds(new Rectangle(250, 180, 75, 20));
    jButton1.setText("Gonder");
    jButton1.setBounds(new Rectangle(135, 210, 75, 21));
    jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jButton1_actionPerformed(e);
            }
        });
    jLabel3.setText("Ogrenci ID: ");
    jLabel3.setBounds(new Rectangle(5, 30, 100, 15));
    jTextField3.setBounds(new Rectangle(80, 25, 120, 20));
    jScrollPane1.setBounds(new Rectangle(5, 50, 350, 115));
    jScrollPane1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                int row = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
                String book = model.getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
                jTextField1.setText(book);
                System.out.println(book);
                String stuID = model.getValueAt(row, 1).toString();
                jTextField2.setText(stuID);
            }
        });
    jButton2.setText("Ara");
    jButton2.setBounds(new Rectangle(285, 25, 75, 21));
    jButton2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jButton2_actionPerformed(e);
            }
        });
    jScrollPane1.getViewport().add(jTable1, null);
    this.getContentPane().add(jButton2, null);
    this.getContentPane().add(jScrollPane1, null);
    this.getContentPane().add(jTextField3, null);
    this.getContentPane().add(jLabel3, null);
    this.getContentPane().add(jButton1, null);
    this.getContentPane().add(jTextField2, null);
    this.getContentPane().add(jLabel2, null);
    this.getContentPane().add(jTextField1, null);
    this.getContentPane().add(jLabel1, null);
    String header [] ={"Kitap No", "Ogrenci No"};
    for(int i = 0; i < header.length; i++){
        model.addColumn(header[i]);
        }
}
```

Comment: Why are you adding a MouseListener to the JScrollPane? Shouldn't you be adding it to the JTable? Next we'll need to discuss your not using layout managers, but that's for a different discussion.

Comment: because i thought the scrollpane is liked that a container of jtable

Comment: But you do not desire to listen for mouse clicks on the JScrollPane. You are interested in clicks in the JTable. And note that the JScrollPane is not the JTable's container as it is held by the Viewport, but that is a non-issue here.

Comment: Other issues: avoid null layout and absolute component positioning as it is extremely difficult to maintain. And you want to give your variables names that make sense and that makes your code self-commenting. It is very difficult for us to understand what your code is doing when you use variable names like jTextField2. Why not addressTextField or some other name that describes its function?

Comment: i'm so sorry for my faults please forgive me. i'm newbie

Comment: There's nothing to apologize for. I'm just posting criticisms of your code, not of you, so that you can improve the code.

Answer (score 1):

I recomend using the [TableCellListener](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/) class. Then you simply go:

```
//Creating an action for the Listener to use
Action action = new AbstractAction()
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    //The code to do when the action is performed
    TableCellListener tcl = (TableCellListener)e.getSource();
    <yourTextField>.setText(tcl.getNewValue());
}
};
//Nothing else needed! Listens automatically
TableCellListener tcl = new TableCellListener(table, action);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use [MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) to perform the task then this code might be helpful. Create a `CustomMouseListener` class and when ever click happens then just call the getSelectedData(..) method such that it will set the value to the `JTextField`. Setting should be done only from when the mouse is `pressed`, `clicked` or `entered`.

```
class TableMouseListener implements MouseListener {  

   private JTable table; 
   private JTextField textField;   

   public TableMouseListener(JTable table, JTextField textField) {
  this.table = table;
      this.textField = textField;           
   }

 public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { 
          getSelectedData(JTable table);
 }  

 public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}  

 public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
           getSelectedData(JTable table);
 }  

 public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}  

 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
          getSelectedData(JTable table);
 } 

/**
 *  Get the selected row using selectedRow(..) method. Append entire row to the String and set this string to the JTextFIeld.  
*/
public getSelectedData(JTable table) {
        // Get the selected row from the table.
          int selectedRow = table.getSelectedRow();
          String setToTextField = new String();
          for(int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
              setToTextField += table.getValueAt(selectedRow, i) + "  ";
          }
          // Finally set this to your JTextField.
         textField.setText(setToTextField);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to use the JTable's MouseClicked Event. Use the following code:

```
private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel(); //create a model
    int selectedRowIndex = jTable1.getSelectedRow(); //get selected row
    String id = (String) dtm.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 0); //get the primary key to fetch data.
    try {
        ResultSet rs = DBCon.getData("Select * from stock where pd_id= '"+id+"'"); //dont worry about dbcon.getdata, its my class to get data.
        while(rs.next()){    //u can use normal query
            pd_id.setText(rs.getString("pd_id"));  //these are my textfields
            pd_name.setText(rs.getString("pd_name"));
            pd_qtys.setText(rs.getString("pd_qtys"));
            pd_qtyw.setText(rs.getString("pd_qtyw"));
            pd_price.setText(rs.getString("pd_price"));
            pd_pkg.setText(rs.getString("pd_pkg"));
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ExistingStock.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you have to convert `model.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(),0);`to `String`

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();

String textField = (String) model.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(),0);  
String textField1 = (String) model.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(),1);
```

and now just set `textField` and `textField1` to   `jTextField1` and `jTextField2`

```
jTextField1.setText(textField);
jTextField2.setText(textField1);
```